# Swift 4 - Firebase observe child changed and update the view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bit complicated question to explain but i will try to be as much clear as I can...

I am retrieving from firebase same values. Specifically I have a Post class and a User Class.
So part of my firebase structure is like so:
[image]

In myPost i have all the postId associated with the user.
When the view loads i get all the postID associated to the user from myPosts and from them i get all the post from Posts and then show them in the view.

In details here's the function i Use to fetch the posts:

```
var FEED_REF = Database.database().reference().child("myPosts")
func observeFeed(withUserId id: String, kPagination: Int, loadMore: Bool, postCount: Int? = 0, completion: @escaping (Post, FirebaseUser) -> Void, isHiddenIndicator:  @escaping (_ isHiddenIndicator: Bool?) -> Void, isEmpty: @escaping () -> Void) {
    FEED_REF.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if !snapshot.hasChild(id) {
            isEmpty()
            return
        }
    }
    let query = FEED_REF.child(id).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: UInt(kPagination))
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        print("Got Snap in feed Observer")
        var items = snapshot.children.allObjects
        if loadMore {
            if items.count <= postCount! {
                isHiddenIndicator(true)
                return
            }
            items.removeLast(postCount!)
        }
        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var results = Array(repeating: (Post(), FirebaseUser()), count: items.count)
        for (index, item) in (items as! [DataSnapshot]).enumerated() {
            myGroup.enter()
            Api.Post.observePost(withId: item.key, completion: { (post) in
                Api.User.observeUser(withId: post.uid, completion: { (user) in
                    results[index] = (post, user)
                    myGroup.leave()
                })
            })
        }
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            for result in results {
                completion(result.0, result.1)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Here the function to observe posts:

```
 let POSTS_REF = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")

 func observePost(withId id: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> Void) {
    POSTS_REF.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let post = Post.getPost(dictionary: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(post)
        }
    })
}
```

Here the function to observe users:

```
let USER_REF = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

func observeUser(withId uid: String, completion: @escaping(FirebaseUser) -> Void) {
    USER_REF.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            let user = FirebaseUser.getUser(dictionary: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(user)
        }
    }
}
```

In my viewDidLoad i call this function to update the view:

```
func loadPosts() {
    activityIndicatorHome.startAnimating()
    guard let currentUserId = Api.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid else {return}
    Api.Feed.observeFeed(withUserId: currentUserId, kPagination: kPagination, loadMore: false, completion: { (post, user) in
        print("1")
        self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
        self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.activityIndicatorHome.stopAnimating()
    }, isHiddenIndicator: { (bool) in
        print("2")

    }) {
        print("3")
        self.activityIndicatorHome.stopAnimating()
        self.emptyTableViewDefaultText()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Everything works fine if there are no changes.
What I am trying to do now is to observe the changes.
Meaning if the user add or remove a post i would like to call loadPosts() and update the view.

I tried to use this:

```
    var MYPOSTS_REF = Database.database().reference().child("myPosts")
   func getMyPostInHome(userId: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void, isEmpty: @escaping () -> Void) {
    MYPOSTS_REF.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if !snapshot.hasChild(userId) {
            isEmpty()
            return
        }
    }
    MYPOSTS_REF.child(userId).observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
        //get the Added/Removed post id here
    }
}
```

But it seems I cannot get the post Id

I hope I've been able to explain everything... I've tried to be as much clear as I could..
If not please let me know.

Could somebody help me?
Thank you.

------UPDATE
I am observing the childAdded like so

```
func observePostAdded(userId: String, completion: @escaping (Post, FirebaseUser) -> Void) {
    MYPOSTS_REF.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let key = snapshot.key
        print("KEY \(key)")
        Api.Post.getMyPosts(withId: key, completion: { (post) in
            Api.User.observeUser(withId: post.uid, completion: { (user) in
                completion(post, user)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There you are observing for changes in child nodes, so it won't be execute if any post is added or removed. To do that you have to use `.childAdded` or `.childRemoved` respectively.

Also there's a `.childValue` observer type that just executes every time any node is added/removed/modified.

You can check the firebase documentation with related info here: 
[Firebase - Working with Lists of Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to get it execute by using .childAdded or .childRemoved. Issue is that it return the value more than one time. So basically the first time i add a post it works but the second it will add two times the same value the third 3 times and so on.... honestly i don't get why..

Comment: I am using this:  MYPOSTS_REF.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) and the the two previous function to get the post and the user

Comment: can you show an updated code about those changes you have made?

Comment: Can someone add a sample code snippit, I can not get my .childchanged observer to call, but everything complies right!?